# What mechanism is used by Linux (or hardware) to ensure that any interrupt capable device does not cause too many interrupts?

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, hardware, interrupt

At the level of interrupts, one would think that there has to some way for a maximum rate to be defined. Otherwise, a malicious device might be able to slow down the system, by continuously giving off interrupts. It would seem that some such limiting, can be done either at the level of the bus hardware, the interrupt control hardware, or at the level of operating system code. Can someone give a broad over-view of this topic?

Comment: I dont know the answer to your question, or even if this will be helpful, but I just found a utility called `irqbalance` which might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel does not offer any facility to define a maximum rate of interrupts. Only hardware components own limitations will consequently.

Some specific drivers (network adaptors for example) might, for some compatible devices, give the opportunity to limit the interrupt rate but that is somehow an exception and won't prevent whatever broken device to flood the system with interrupts.

Comment: what about perf and ulimit?

Comment: @j0h : *ulimit* only enables the admin to maximize  the **use** (by some user) of system-wide resources. It offers just no way to maximize whatever hardware propension to consume other hardware resources. *perf* is nothing more than a profiler tool that is a tool to collect and analyze performance and trace data. As such it offers just no way to act on whatever tuneable.